# How to use OR operator in RF?

Tags: robotframework

My testcase needed to set two or more value in order to evaluate with ${value} but this syntax does not work!
I appreciate if anybody could guide me.

```
${status} =  Evaluate  ${value} != 11 || 5
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a technical description of a problem. What does not work? [ask]

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Evaluate` the expression must be valid Python.
In your case you could use:

```
${status} =  Evaluate  ${value} != 11 or ${value} != 5
```

or

```
${status} =  Evaluate  ${value} not in [11, 5]
```